# Paged columns layout

Tags: css, angularjs, multiple-columns

I'm trying to achieve a layout with multiple columns filled with elements of the same width (column-width) but with varying heights. The idea is to have some form of pagination, where you could either scroll the container and have it adjust to only show full columns, or click on a button to see the next or previous columns.

I've put a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xfThSptMFDaVpICPGhCz?p=preview) to illustrate the idea.

My issue is that no matter what I do, I can't seem to get rid of the column-gap, which seems to have a default minimum. I also can't figure out how the gap size is determined, so I can't really calculate how much I should scroll the container.
Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the width you set on the `.el` elements, change this width to 100% and you gap will be removed.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/S8TmV/7/)**

HTML :

```
<div id="cols">
    <div>ELEMENT</div>
    <div>ELEMENT</div>
    <div>ELEMENT</div>
    ...
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#cols {
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-column-width: 25em;
    -moz-column-width: 25em;
    -ms-column-width: 25em;
    -o-column-width: 25em;
    column-width: 25em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 0;
    -moz-column-gap: 0;
    -ms-column-gap: 0;
    -o-column-gap: 0;
    column-gap: 0;
}
#cols > div{
    background:gold;
    height:50px;
    margin:5px 0;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%; /*<-- this line */
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That was more or less the issue. Doing that or setting column-width to e.g. 300px (and .el width to 300px) worked. However I do have another issue now: when I set column-width to 300px and .el width to 100%, the actual width of .el is more than 300px, it's actually 415px. At least the gap isn't there anymore, but I don't understand this width

Comment: @axelcdv glad I could help, sorry, I was totaly wrong in previous comment. See the specs of `column-width` to understand your issue here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-width it sais the specified column width is only a suggestion and browser computes it according to container width.